# Drawing an image at floating points - Java

Tags: java, java-2d

Graphics2D's drawImage() method requires strictly integers.

How could one draw an image using floating points in Java2D, if at all?

If not what would SO recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - the screen is partitioned into pixels, which are represented as integers. You physically cant tell the screen to draw something at half a pixel because that's not how screens work.

The best solution is just to round your float to the nearest integer and draw the object there.

Comment: I realize this was a very dumb question... Thanks anyway!

Comment: @MitchWeaver It's not a dumb question. Don't worry about it.